Label text in CarouselView using MCT Popup is overflowing in MAUI
Using a CarouselView within a MAUI Community Toolkit (MCT) Popup, labels set within the carousel datatemplate appear to be overflowing. Setting a fixed WidthRequest smaller than the width of the popup, does work for the label area. However, the text still overflows. As it appears, the overflowing happens only on the right side of the label. It seems like the label area has a correct width but the text within it is much wider.
It's nothing too special, just a carouselview with items:
<tk:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:m="clr-namespace:CarouselPopupTest.Models"
          xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
          x:Class="CarouselPopupTest.Controls.Popup_Instructions">
    <Frame>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Global.Instructions}"
                          IndicatorView="indicatorView"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                          Margin="0,0,0,16"
                          Loop="False">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:Instruct">
                        <Frame>
                            <VerticalStackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       WidthRequest="224"/>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                                       WidthRequest="224"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       WidthRequest="224"/>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
            <IndicatorView MaximumVisible="8"
                           x:Name="indicatorView"
                           HorizontalOptions="End">
                <IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource IndicatorViewIndicator}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
            </IndicatorView>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                <Button ImageSource="btn_check.svg"
                        Grid.Column="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Frame>
</tk:Popup>

Here's how it appears when viewing the popup-carousel in debug on any device:

Note: This screenshot was made after removing the <Image>.
Image views actually do render fine. Only the label elements keep overflowing for some unknown reason. Is this a bug or am I doing something that I'm not supposed to do here?

What platform and .NET version do you use? It's recommended to use Border instead of Frame.

For this project 'm using .NET 7 MAUI and I'm unable to test iOS just yet, but it happens on Android.

I cannot get the same result. You set the same WidthRequest for the two labels, while from the picture they are not the same.

Have you tried using a Grid instead of a StackLayout?

No I hadn't yet, so I just changed the VerticalStackLayouts into Grids with fixed row heights and column widths. The heights and widths are being applied but the text is still overflowing.

I reproduce this issue. Seems that it only happens at the first time, When swiping to other items and then swipe back, the text will not be overflowing.

@LiqunShen-MSFT Thanks for the confirmation. That is exactly what happens, the first time only. So I think it's safe to assume it is a bug? Perhaps I should raise an issue at MCT on Github.

I reproduce this issue in .NET7. The ext is overflowing in the CarouselView in a CommunityToolkit Popup only for the first time it render.
The workaround is to use .NET8 with the latest CommunityToolkit Maui (Version8.0.1), which seems to fix the issue.
Hope it helps!

Thanks, this did solve the problem for good. However, the CarouselView used to work fine before but suddenly got bugged using dotNET 7. Is there anything else known that could have caused it while I was using dotNET 7 for this project?

Have you ever updated the Visual Studio?

Yes, now that you mention it. That musf've done it.
